# Selecting average prices for each of the last 30 days in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Have this query that I use to get the average price of the products in a product category for each of the last 30 days:

```sql
SELECT DATE(bsbp.date) AS pricedate, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(bsbp.date)) AS unixdate,
    ROUND(AVG((bsbp.price / 100) * (bc.exchangerate / 100)), 0) AS avgprice
FROM bd_shopbikesprices bsbp, bd_categoriesshopbikes bcsb, bd_shopbikes bsb,
bd_shops bs, bd_currencies bc 
WHERE bsbp.shopbikeid = bcsb.shopbikeid AND bcsb.categoryid = 94
    AND bsbp.shopbikeid = bsb.id AND bsb.shopid = bs.id AND bs.feedcurrencyid = bc.id 
    AND bsbp.price > 0 
GROUP BY DATE(bsbp.date) ORDER BY pricedate DESC LIMIT 30
```

Problem is that the table with the prices (bsbp) only contains price changes, i.e. the last price of each product where the price was different than the previous price of the product (or where the product was new and therefore didn't have a previous price).

Like this:

```
shopbikeid|date|price
890061|2016-07-27 02:50:01|29999
890061|2016-07-21 03:21:51|49999
890061|2016-07-17 21:20:55|29999
890061|2016-06-30 04:41:36|49999
```

Currently the query takes the average new prices for each day, which isn't the actual average price since the average new prices only covers the products where the price was changed/new products.

My question is how the query should be rewritten so each daily average is the average price of all products on that day, including products where the prices was changed before that day.

Can it be done somehow with a nice query? (the database is a MySQL database)

Comment: That's a rather complex query. No one is going to be able to answer it without trying it out first. For that CREATE TABLE statements are needed

Comment: Don't use comma join syntax. And consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similiar case and solved it using the following approach:

- Create a temporary table `tmpLatestDates` from your price table, in which you group by the product and use `MAX(date)`
- Create another temporary table `tmpLatestPrices`: Join `tmpLatestDates`with your price table on product and date, only keeping the rows from `tmpLatestDates`. This gives you the latest price for each product.
- Run your original query on `tmpLatestPrices`

When you do this with large datasets you'll want to add indexes to the temporary tables after you created them. Also don't forget to drop the temporary tables after you're done.

The most practical way of handling it would be to put all queries in a stored procedure.

**Edit**: You can follow the same logic using subqueries, but I find the temp. table approach easier to follow plus it simplifies maintenance later on.

Comment: Ended up with a somewhat similar solution, i.e. using a new table for storing average prices for each category daily (via a PHP cron job)